# Gulp watch not working on Node 4.6.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm really desperate at the moment, I had a working project, with a working gulpfile.js file going, everything worked great before I updated node to 4.6.0, I tried to make this an issue on git on Gulp, but they told me it isn't a Gulp problem, so i'm not sure how to fix it.

My setup is

System: Windows 7 64x
Node: 4.6.0
Gulp: 3.9.1
npm: 2.15.9

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
   sass = require('gulp-sass');
   notify = require("gulp-notify");
   jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
   uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
   rename = require('gulp-rename'),
   concat = require('gulp-concat'),
   cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin')

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('sass/main.sass')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'sass file compiled!' }));
});

gulp.task('jsScripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./js/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('web-app.js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/output'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'JS Scripts done!' }));
});

gulp.task('watch',function() {
    gulp.watch('./sass/main/*.sass',['styles']);
    gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['jsScripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['jsScripts', 'styles', 'watch']);
```

As i said, it was working great before the update, now all it does, it runs the tasks and "watch" finishes just like that, i don't even think is compiling the sass files, I installed all my dependencies as I've always done it, I follow a tutorial: https://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp and it worked fine all the time.

is it a Node.js problem? I'm not sure what to do. ty

Answer (score 0):

`Node-sass` is installed depending on the current version of node used, so if you changed versions then it won't compile.

Remove your **node_modules** folder and run a fresh `npm install`

Comment: I just did that, and it didn't work, same result, updated everything, and it happens the same thing, here is a screen of my command promt:
http://i64.tinypic.com/15fkjub.jpg

I don't know what is preventing the watch task to run as it should be.

Comment: Oh i see whats happening. The build is failing due to linting errors in ur javascript

Comment: add the following at the top of your javascript file:

/*global $, jQuery*/
'use strict';

This will let jshint know that jquery will be a global variable and not throw errors due to not being declared in the document.

Please note: using strict mode may make more errors appear depending on the quality of your javascript

Comment: It did bring an error that it cannot be solved, however, even if i remove that task completely, and just stick to the SASS compiling task, it has the same effect, Watch just finishes, also, I recalling having jsHint errors before, and everything worked fine still, the notifications were on my bottom right corner and everytime i saved a sass file it was compiled, here is another screen of my prompt with no JS task involved at all, removed from the gulpfile: http://i64.tinypic.com/kei3qx.jpg

Comment: Hmm weird - is almost like it can't find any files top process as theres no errors. Perhaps try adding a ./ into the glob. gulp.src('./sass/main.sass'). I know it doesnt make a difference on my machine, but perhaps windows behaves differently with filepaths.

Comment: Tried different paths and it keeps not working, at all, it doesn't even compile de sass files, even if i specify the process "gulp styles" , it just says starting "styles".... <br/>
        finished "styles" after 19ms<br/>
So i'm not sure what is the issue, as i said earlier, before i updated Node to 4.6.0, everything was working really smooth :/